# sshfs troubleshooting: what would cause openssl to fail?

Tags: openssl, openssh, sftp, sshfs, ipkg

I believe sshfs requires an sftp server on the remote computer (router):

```
ipkg list_installed | grep -i sftp
openssh-sftp-server - 5.9p1-1 - sftp-server only from a FREE version of the SSH protocol suite of network connectivity tools.
```

The goal is to invoke sshfs to mount a remote directory:

```
sshfs user@mydomain.asuscomm.com:/mnt/CRUZERFIT16/directory/ /home/user/Documents/scpbox/
```

This sshfs setup was working correctly in May, however, a family member reset the router.  sshfs returns an error:

```
remote host has disconnected
total 0
```

Attempt to remote sftp into router returned:

```
/opt/libexec/sftp-server: can't load library 'libcrypto.so.0.9.8'
Connection closed
```

`ipkg list_installed | grep openssl` returned:

> openssl - 0.9.8v-2 - Openssl provides the ssl implementation in
>   libraries libcrypto and libssl, and is needed by many other
>   applications and librari

openssl successfully reinstalled on router:

```
ipkg -force-reinstall install  openssl
```

and **am now able to sftp & sshfs** into target router.
Not sure why openssl was unavailable before reinstalling.  Is there a test command to determine if openssl is available for the sftp server?